# Refactoring NatsPublisher. DIing IOptions is potentially a bad decision

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, nats.io

I made a wrapper for the NATS Client which basically adds ASP.NET DI functionality. There are two "issues" that I think should be fixed.

1. I think `_jetStream` should be lazy loaded.

> Lazy initialization is usually used whereby you only load or initialize an object *when you first need it*.

```cs
_jetStreamFactory = new Lazy<IJetStream>(() => connection.CreateJetStreamContext());
```

2. The library is meant to extend `ConnectionFactory`'s capabilities with additional configuration options (Decorator pattern). Knowing that, I don't think it's appropriate to dependency inject `IOptions<NatsProducerConfiguration>` in the `NatsPublisher` class because it violates the main idea.
3. If there is anything else

### The code that the question is about

```cs
public class ProducerConfiguration
{
    public string[]? Servers { get; init; }
    public string? Url { get; init; }
    public string? User { get; init; }
    public string? Password { get; init; }
    public required string Stream { get; init; }
    public required string Subject { get; init; }
}

public interface IPublisher
{
    ValueTask<PublishAck> Publish<T>(T payload) where T : class;

    ValueTask<PublishAck> PublishAsync(byte[] payload, IEnumerable<(string, string)> headers);

    ValueTask<PublishAck> PublishWithDeduplicationIdAsync(byte[] payload, string id);
}

public sealed class NatsPublisher : IPublisher
{
    private readonly ProducerConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IJetStream _jetStream;

    public NatsPublisher(IOptions<ProducerConfiguration> options, IConnection connection)
    {
        _configuration = options.Value;

        JetStreamUtils.CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(connection, _configuration.Stream, _configuration.Subject);
        _jetStream = connection.CreateJetStreamContext();
    }

    public async ValueTask<PublishAck> Publish<T>(T payload)
        where T : class
    {
        var data = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(payload);

        var msg = new Msg(_configuration.Subject, null, null, data);

        return await _jetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }

    public async ValueTask<PublishAck> PublishAsync(byte[] payload)
    {
        var msg = new Msg(_configuration.Subject, null, null, payload);
        return await _jetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }

    public async ValueTask<PublishAck> PublishAsync(byte[] payload, IEnumerable<(string, string)> headers)
    {
        var msg = new Msg(_configuration.Subject, null, null, payload);

        foreach (var (header, val) in headers)
        {
            msg.Header[header] = val;
        }

        return await _jetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }

    public async ValueTask<PublishAck> PublishWithDeduplicationIdAsync(byte[] payload, string id)
    {
        var msg = new Msg(_configuration.Subject, null, null, payload)
        {
            Header = { ["Nats-Msg-Id"] = id }
        };

        return await _jetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

### The library itself

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddNatsClient(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<Options>? configureOptions = null,
        ServiceLifetime connectionServiceLifeTime = ServiceLifetime.Transient)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(services);

        var defaultOptions = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();
        configureOptions?.Invoke(defaultOptions);
        services.AddSingleton(defaultOptions);

        services.AddSingleton<ConnectionFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<INatsClientConnectionFactory, NatsClientConnectionFactoryDecorator>();

        services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IConnection), provider =>
        {
            var options = provider.GetRequiredService<Options>();
            var connectionFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<INatsClientConnectionFactory>();
            return connectionFactory.CreateConnection(options);
        }, connectionServiceLifeTime));

        services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IEncodedConnection), provider =>
        {
            var options = provider.GetRequiredService<Options>();
            var connectionFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<INatsClientConnectionFactory>();
            return connectionFactory.CreateEncodedConnection(options);
        }, connectionServiceLifeTime));

        return services;
    }
}

public interface INatsClientConnectionFactory
{
    IConnection CreateConnection(Action<Options>? configureOptions = null);

    IConnection CreateConnection(Options options);

    IEncodedConnection CreateEncodedConnection(Action<Options>? configureOptions = null);

    IEncodedConnection CreateEncodedConnection(Options options);
}

public sealed class NatsClientConnectionFactoryDecorator : INatsClientConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

    public NatsClientConnectionFactoryDecorator(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public IConnection CreateConnection(Action<Options>? configureOptions = default)
    {
        var options = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();
        configureOptions?.Invoke(options);
        return CreateConnection(options);
    }

    public IConnection CreateConnection(Options options)
    {
        return _connectionFactory.CreateConnection(options);
    }

    public IEncodedConnection CreateEncodedConnection(Action<Options>? configureOptions = default)
    {
        var options = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();
        configureOptions?.Invoke(options);
        return CreateEncodedConnection(options);
    }

    public IEncodedConnection CreateEncodedConnection(Options options)
    {
        return _connectionFactory.CreateEncodedConnection(options);
    }
}

public static class JetStreamUtils
{
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // STREAM INFO / CREATE / UPDATE
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static StreamInfo? GetStreamInfoOrNullWhenNotExist(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName)
    {
        try
        {
            return jsm.GetStreamInfo(streamName);
        }
        catch (NATSJetStreamException e)
        {
            if (e.ErrorCode == 404)
            {
                return null;
            }

            throw;
        }
    }

    public static bool StreamExists(IConnection c, string streamName)
    {
        return GetStreamInfoOrNullWhenNotExist(c.CreateJetStreamManagementContext(), streamName) != null;
    }

    public static bool StreamExists(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName)
    {
        return GetStreamInfoOrNullWhenNotExist(jsm, streamName) != null;
    }

    public static void ExitIfStreamExists(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName)
    {
        if (StreamExists(jsm, streamName))
        {
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public static void ExitIfStreamNotExists(IConnection c, string streamName)
    {
        if (!StreamExists(c, streamName))
        {
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStream(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName, StorageType storageType,
        params string[] subjects)
    {
        var sc = StreamConfiguration.Builder()
            .WithName(streamName)
            .WithStorageType(storageType)
            .WithSubjects(subjects)
            .Build();

        var si = jsm.AddStream(sc);

        return si;
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStream(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string stream, params string[] subjects)
    {
        return CreateStream(jsm, stream, StorageType.Memory, subjects);
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStream(IConnection c, string stream, params string[] subjects)
    {
        return CreateStream(c.CreateJetStreamManagementContext(), stream, StorageType.Memory, subjects);
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStreamExitWhenExists(IConnection c, string streamName, params string[] subjects)
    {
        return CreateStreamExitWhenExists(c.CreateJetStreamManagementContext(), streamName, subjects);
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStreamExitWhenExists(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName,
        params string[] subjects)
    {
        ExitIfStreamExists(jsm, streamName);
        return CreateStream(jsm, streamName, StorageType.Memory, subjects);
    }

    public static void CreateStreamWhenDoesNotExist(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string stream, params string[] subjects)
    {
        try
        {
            jsm.GetStreamInfo(stream);
            return;
        }
        catch (NATSJetStreamException)
        {
        }

        var sc = StreamConfiguration.Builder()
            .WithName(stream)
            .WithStorageType(StorageType.Memory)
            .WithSubjects(subjects)
            .Build();
        jsm.AddStream(sc);
    }

    public static void CreateStreamWhenDoesNotExist(IConnection c, string stream, params string[] subjects)
    {
        CreateStreamWhenDoesNotExist(c.CreateJetStreamManagementContext(), stream, subjects);
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName,
        StorageType storageType, params string[] subjects)
    {
        var si = GetStreamInfoOrNullWhenNotExist(jsm, streamName);
        if (si == null)
        {
            return CreateStream(jsm, streamName, storageType, subjects);
        }

        var sc = si.Config;
        var needToUpdate = false;
        foreach (var sub in subjects)
        {
            if (!sc.Subjects.Contains(sub))
            {
                needToUpdate = true;
                sc.Subjects.Add(sub);
            }
        }

        if (needToUpdate)
        {
            si = jsm.UpdateStream(sc);
        }

        return si;
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(IJetStreamManagement jsm, string streamName,
        params string[] subjects)
    {
        return CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(jsm, streamName, StorageType.Memory, subjects);
    }

    public static StreamInfo CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(IConnection c, string stream, params string[] subjects)
    {
        return CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(c.CreateJetStreamManagementContext(), stream, StorageType.Memory,
            subjects);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // PUBLISH
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void Publish(IConnection c, string subject, int count)
    {
        Publish(c.CreateJetStreamContext(), subject, "data", count);
    }

    public static void Publish(IJetStream js, string subject, int count)
    {
        Publish(js, subject, "data", count);
    }

    public static void Publish(IJetStream js, string subject, string prefix, int count)
    {
        for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++)
        {
            var data = prefix + x;
            js.Publish(subject, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        }
    }

    public static void PublishInBackground(IJetStream js, string subject, string prefix, int count)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++)
                {
                    js.Publish(subject, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prefix + "-" + x));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100); // give the publish thread a little time to get going
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // READ MESSAGES
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static IList<Msg> ReadMessagesAck(ISyncSubscription sub, int timeout = 1000)
    {
        IList<Msg> messages = new List<Msg>();
        var keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing)
        {
            try
            {
                var msg = sub.NextMessage(timeout);
                messages.Add(msg);
                msg.Ack();
            }
            catch (NATSTimeoutException)
            {
                keepGoing = false;
            }
        }

        return messages;
    }
}
```

### How to use

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<NatsProducerConfiguration>(options =>
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Nats").Bind(options));
var natsConfiguration = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Nats").Get<NatsProducerConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddNatsClient(options =>
{
    options.Servers = natsConfiguration?.Servers;
    options.Url = natsConfiguration?.Url;
    options.User = natsConfiguration?.User;
    options.Password = natsConfiguration?.Password;

    options.MaxReconnect = 5;
    options.ReconnectWait = 5000;
});
```

Comment: What’s the specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully `CreateStreamWhenDoesNotExist` does what it says. By the way, [`JetStreamUtils`](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.net/blob/master/src/Samples/JetStreamExampleUtils/JsUtils.cs) was taken from the official C# NATS Client Samples.

I believe this fixes the pitfalls I described.

Perhaps you got a better idea?

```cs
public interface INatsPublisher
{
    ValueTask PublishAsync<T>(string stream, string subject, T message) where T : class;

    ValueTask PublishAsync<T>(string stream, string subject, T message, IEnumerable<(string, string)> headers)
        where T : class;

    ValueTask PublishDeduplicationIdAsync<T>(string stream, string subject, T message, string id)
        where T : class;
}

public sealed class NatsPublisher : INatsPublisher
{
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    private readonly Lazy<IJetStream> _jetStreamFactory;

    public NatsPublisher(IConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _jetStreamFactory = new Lazy<IJetStream>(() => connection.CreateJetStreamContext());
    }

    private IJetStream JetStream => _jetStreamFactory.Value;

    public async ValueTask PublishAsync<T>(string stream, string subject, T message) where T : class
    {
        JetStreamUtils.CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(_connection, stream, subject);

        var payload = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(message);
        var msg = new Msg(subject, null, null, payload);
        await JetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }

    public async ValueTask PublishAsync<T>(string stream, string subject, T message, IEnumerable<(string, string)> headers)
        where T : class
    {
        JetStreamUtils.CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(_connection, stream, subject);

        var payload = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(message);
        var msg = new Msg(subject, null, null, payload);

        foreach (var (header, val) in headers)
        {
            msg.Header[header] = val;
        }

        await JetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }

    public async ValueTask PublishDeduplicationIdAsync<T>(string stream, string subject, T message, string id)
        where T : class
    {
        JetStreamUtils.CreateStreamOrUpdateSubjects(_connection, stream, subject);

        var payload = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(message);
        var msg = new Msg(subject, null, null, payload)
        {
            Header = { ["Nats-Msg-Id"] = id }
        };

        await JetStream.PublishAsync(msg);
    }
}
```